Is it possible to integrate .webm in Magento 2 Page Builder image upload?
In the Page Builder banner background image, I need to upload a .webm format video because the GIF reduces the video quality.If .webm integration is possible, how can I do that?
When I tried to integrate .webp, I was able to do it but for .webm integration, I'm stuck and not sure how to do it. If someone knows how, it would be a big help.
